# Tomcat7 "HTTP ERROR 403" on localhost login page

Tags: java, tomcat7, http-status-code-403

I have the following error, when accessing the url "http://localhost:8080/manager/html"

"Access to localhost was denied"
"You don't have authorization to view this page."
"HTTP ERROR 403"

The login page is not opened, do not request for user authentication

This only happen when is executed in the host that the tomcat is installed; I can access the page within the local net.

Thank you and best regards
spc

Comment: What do you mean "executed in the host"? Sounds like you need to point to the server that tomcat is installed on. localhost is the machine you are passing the url from. If this is not the same machine with tomcat then you need to address that machine.

Comment: I instal tomcat in a machine, at installation works fine, I can ran the path localhost, but now I can reach it only with one machine in the local network. Neither the host that is installed, neither the public url.

Comment: Sorry I was on vacation for the last week. But basically localhost address is only for the machine you are currently on. If you are installing it on another machine then it is not addressable at localhost but rather that machine's IP or domain name.